# Bug identification: rectangular green and copper creature

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

I've found a very strange-looking creature on the street of a local park (Russia, Urals). It was 2-3 cm long,  almost rectangular, with green and copper colors, running somewhere with low speed. I've never seen anything like it before. Here's a picture (sorry for the quality):

[image]

Does anybody know what this is?

Comment: I tried zooming in on this picture and wasn't able to; that having been said, from what I can see you have a mating pair of whatever these are (I do know the order, and think I know the family, but I am having a tough time locating a web-based resource that will help in a deeper identification).

Comment: @ArthurJFrost This is an interesting option. I think they would move more chaotically if they were mating (and this thing crossed a road on my eyes), but I'm no expert.

Comment: @ArthurJFrost you are correct, I see legs at both ends.

Comment: Some sort of [Pentatomidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentatomidae), but that's as close as I can get with this photo.